# Installing matplotlib using pip in cmd finishes without actually installing

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I'm trying to install matplotlib library using pip from cmd (Windows 10), but the installation finishes after the download without actually installing the package. I don't get any error message, it just finishes.

cmd output:

```
C:\Users\username>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

C:\Users\username>
```

Trying without cached version doesn't help.

```
C:\Users\username>pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (9.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.1MB 25.5MB/s

C:\Users\username>
```

I also tried downloading the .whl file and installing manually, same problem.

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads>pip install matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\username\downloads\matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

C:\Users\username\Downloads>
```

After all this matplotlib doesn't exist as an installed library. Other libraries are being installed and working fine without problems.

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads>pip show matplotlib

C:\Users\username\Downloads>
```

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads>pip show keras
Name: Keras
Version: 2.2.4
Summary: Deep Learning for humans
Home-page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Author: Francois Chollet
Author-email: francois.chollet@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: h5py, numpy, scipy, six, keras-applications, pyyaml, keras-preprocessing
Required-by:
```

I've done the whole exercise using pip3 also, the results are the same.

I've done this in cmd, powershell, and VSCode's powershell terminal as well, still same result.

Any idea what is happening here and how to solve it?

**Note:** I've replaced my user name with "username" in the cmd outputs.

Edit: I also tried installing a different version of matplotlib, but still getting the same result.

Comment: Did you try a different version of matplotlib, just to see if there is something wrong with the wheels of this particular version?

Comment: This is interesting. What is the output (if any) after `Using cached ...` line when you run `pip install matplotlib -vvv`?

Comment: @hoefling using -vvv it gives a very long output with the last two lines being 

`Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Downloading from URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=4442ce720907f67a79d45de9ada47be81ce17e6c2f448b3c64765af93f6829c9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/) (requires-python:>=3.6)`

Still no luck though.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is running this code from command line in the following order (Windows users):

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip uninstall matplotlib
```

This would pop the question: Proceed (y/n)?

```
y
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: The second command gives output
```Skipping matplotlib as it is not installed.```
The third one does nothing after downloading and just finishes, just like everything else